# How to change SharePoint List Views Style using CSOM Programmatically in C#

Tags: view, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have created list view using below code

```
ViewCreationInformation creationInfo = new ViewCreationInformation();
creationInfo.Title ="MyView";
creationInfo.RowLimit = 10;
creationInfo.ViewFields = viewFields.ToArray();
creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = "HTML";
viewCollection.Add(creationInfo);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I want to change the style using CSOM. But there is no option to change the     style using client DLL.Though I tried to update ListViewXML is not getting updated.Kindly help me on this.

Comment: any one help me on this ? :(

Comment: I asked the question again and got an answer that worked:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199612/set-list-view-style-with-csom

Answer (score 0):

////Please add below code with your code

//// Update view style

```
            /*
                * 0-Basic Table
                * 14-Document Details
                * 15-Newsletter
                * 16-Newsletter, no lines
                * 17-Shaded
                * 20-Preview Pane
            */
           ViewCollection oView = list.Views;
            int styleId = 17;
            foreach (View v in oView)
            {
                if (v.Title == "MyView")
                {

                    ctx.Load(v);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(v.ListViewXml);
                    XmlElement element = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//View//ViewStyle");
                    if (element == null)
                    {
                        element = doc.CreateElement("ViewStyle");
                        element.SetAttribute("ID", styleId.ToString());
                        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.SetAttribute("ID", styleId.ToString());
                    }

                    v.ListViewXml = doc.FirstChild.InnerXml;
                    v.Update();                      
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    break;
                }
            }
```